# Como organizar os valores de um array em uma table usando Javascript

Tags: javascript, tabela-html

Olá,
Estou com o seguinte array de exemplo:

```
var users = [
    { DiaDaSemana: 'segunda a sexta', valor: 'joaozinho' },
    { DiaDaSemana: 'segunda a sexta', valor: 'mariazinha' },
    { DiaDaSemana: 'sabados', valor: 'manuel' },
    { DiaDaSemana: 'sabados', valor: 'jose' }
  ];
```

gostaria de saber como poderia organizar usando table programaticamente, com javascript na seguinte maneira:

```
segunda a sexta | sabados
joaozinho       | manuel
mariazinha      | jose
```

Com esse exemplo não consigo criar nem um TH e nem um TD mais as linhas:

```
<body>

    <div id='myDiv'>
        <table id='tabela'>
            <thead id="cabecalho">
                <tr id="linha">

                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script>
        var table = document.getElementById('tabela');
        var thead = document.getElementById('cabecalho');
        var tr = document.getElementById('linha');
        
        var textoInserido = [];
        // var existeLinha = false;

        var newCell = document.createElement('th');

        // Faz um loop para criar as colunas
        for (var j = 0; j < thead.rows.length; j++) {                   
        
                for (let indiceLinha = 0; indiceLinha < tr.cells.length; indiceLinha++) { 
                    
                    <% for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) { %>
                        
                        var existeLinha = tr.cells[indiceLinha].innerText.includes("<%= users[i].DiaDaSemana %>");
                        
                        if(existeLinha == false) {

                            newCell = tr.insertCell(<% i %>);
                            newCell.innerText = "<%= users[i].DiaDaSemana %>";

                            // insere o elemento na lista
                            textoInserido.push("<%= users[i].DiaDaSemana %>"); 

                        }

                    <% } %>           
                    
                }           

        }

        thead.appendChild(tr);

    </script>
```

Estou usando o ejs no auxilio da construção da table
Alguém por favor poderia me dar uma luz nisso?

Comment: Se já tentou de N maneiras, então vc tem algum código feito, certo? Por favor clique em [edit] e adicione este código. Leia também como montar um [mcve]

Comment: @hkotsubo inseri o trecho de código que não funciona. OK ?

Comment: @Ediberto verifica se minha resposta lhe ajuda

Comment: @clonepor onde?

Comment: verifica o post

Answer (score -2):

```js
function separador(users){

let temp={};
let newarray=[];
//inicia um foreache nos users
users.forEach(
        object => {
        //verifica se ja existe
        if(temp[object.DiaDaSemana] !== undefined){
            newarray.push(temp[object.DiaDaSemana]);
            temp= Object.assign(temp,{[object.DiaDaSemana]:[newarray]});
        }else{
            temp= Object.assign(temp,{[object.DiaDaSemana]:[object.valor]});
        }
    
})
    return temp;
}

let users = [
    { DiaDaSemana: 'segunda a sexta', valor: 'joaozinho' },
    { DiaDaSemana: 'sabados', valor: 'manuel' },
    { DiaDaSemana: 'segunda a sexta', valor: 'mariazinha' },
    { DiaDaSemana: 'sabados', valor: 'jose' }
  ];
  
console.log(separador(users));
```